# Write protection of loop device // Read-Only Filesystem

Tags: mount, kernel, selinux

After spending days on that topic I am in need of additional ideas ;)

Facts: MTK6757 / Android 7 / Kernel 4.4.15 / FS EXT4 (No F2FS) / Working Root

I have a fresh and clean 64MB EXT4 .IMG File in `/data/adb`. e2fsck agrees with that ;)

Problem: **Mounting and/or writing to it via Loop Device fails.**

What I have checked:

- Access rights of the file
- Access rights of the block device
- Access rights of the destination dir
- Manually created the block device
- Manually setup via losetup
- Played with all options
- SElinux Permissive / Enforcing

Behaviour:

- It only gets mounted with "mount" because it calls a ioctl BLKROSET (thx  strace)
- Mount and `/proc/mounts` show RW
- As soon as I write (mkdir) to it, it switches to RO
  (dmesg says Switching to RO cause of Buffer I/O error on dev loop0, logical block 0, lost sync page write)
- When I enforce writing it gets written to cache but not to the file

  `ioctl /dev/block/loop0 0x125d 1 mkdir /sbin/.core/img/test`

And now the strange part:

**When the img file is on `/sdcard` it works.**

The SE Context is of course different, but i also tried in Permissive.
When the mounting occurs BEFORE Zygote starts or in Recovery, writing fails also on `/sdcard` (**Update**: Because during boot /sdcard is not available yet)

Anybody any ideas?

**Update:**

It gets even more interesting:
Turns out writing to `/sdcard` only works as long as it is mounted as `sdcardfs`.
If `sdcardfs` is deactivated it gets mounted as FUSE properly, but writing doesnt work anymore.

As all the facts hint toward a `selinux` \ `vold` \ `FS` problem, i tried to restage the sdcardfs evironment.
Assign `root` \ sdcard_rw`and`u:object_r:sdcardfs:s0` to the file in a different directory.
Doesnt work ;(

Then I compared the selinux policies of 2 devices where it works with the problematic one.
Turns out `allow vold block_device : blk_file { ioctl read write create getattr setattr lock append unlink rename open }` is completely missing.
But injecting that doesn't help too...

Any experts or suggestions?